# How to find records that are still active in a transaction table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a transaction table with two event values: CREATE and REMOVE.  There are also `account_id` and `project_id` fields.  I'm trying to determine the number of accounts with 2 or more projects that were created but not removed.

Here is the initial query to get the accounts with more than 2 projects:

```sql
SELECT account_id, count(*) AS counter
FROM projects a
WHERE event = 'INSERT'
GROUP BY account_id
HAVING counter > 1
```

I thought something like this self join would index off of the `project_id` and give me the records from the left table that have the "INSERT" value without the corresponding "REMOVE" value in the left table.  But the data returned isn't what's expected.

```sql
SELECT a.accountid, count(*) AS counter
FROM projects a
         LEFT JOIN projects b ON a.project_id = b.project_id
WHERE a.eventname = 'INSERT'
  AND b.eventname != 'REMOVE'
GROUP BY a.account_id
HAVING counter > 1
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Travelling this road - for a start: (i) Your result includes the identical records on both sides - exclude them by, e.g,  adding ˋa.id <> b.idˋ to the ˋJOINˋ condition. (ii) The not yet removed projects should now have ˋb.eventname IS NULLˋ instead of ˋb.eventname != 'REMOVE'ˋ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that a project is created and removed only once, then you just need to count those values:

```
select account_id,
       sum(case when event = 'CREATE' then 1 else 0 end) as num_creates,
       sum(case when event = 'removes' then 1 else 0 end) as num_removes
from projects p
group by account_id
having num_creates - num_removes >= 2
```